# Text formatting enhancements on Facebook

Tags: facebook, text-formatting

Does Facebook have any text formatting enhancements like [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)? While writing a comment or status update, can I use linked texts or @-referrals? Or is it just like Notepad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you cannot, only @-referrals to friends,events and pages that you are affiliated with on Facebook.

You can only place formatting in [notes](http://www.facebook.com/notes/phwd/facebook-notes-cheat-sheet/307472899342741).

[image: Cheat Sheet]

Comment: Its a good thing too, or else Facebook would turn into MySpace with people copy pasting HTML code to include stupid images everywhere.

Comment: Also, @-referrals only work in posts, not in comments.

Comment: The link is broken (*This content is currently unavailable*). Also, what is a "note" in facebook? Does it still exist?

Answer (score 4):

I can't find any official announcement, but it seems that Markdown is now supported **only when posting as a page**:

[image: Facebook comment in Markdown (with preview)]

Comment: I tried it just now but it didn't seem to render the markdown after posting. Just kept it in plain text...

Comment: @victor did you click the button? You have to toggle it on.

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook Markdown](https://github.com/devxoul/fbmarkdown) is a Google Chrome extension that enables markdown (lightweight markup language with plain text formatting syntax) on Facebook. Facebook Markdown is available in the [Google Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-markdown/domgfmdenhggdpmlmhpemmlopkppoflk).