# How to do bold and italic formatting in Facebook Chat

Tags: facebook, markdown, facebook-messenger

A follow-up to [Text formatting enhancements on Facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12167/text-formatting-enhancements-on-facebook), how does one create bold and italic formatting in Facebook chat? Is it possible to provide emphasis within messages?

I think (maybe I'm going mad) that this used to work, but it hasn't been working lately.

Answer (score 3):

This is what Facebook officially says

````
╔═══════════════════╤══════════╤═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║      Format       │ Example  │                   Instructions                    ║
╠═══════════════════╪══════════╪═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Italic            │  _Text_  │ Type an underscore before and after the text.     ║
╟───────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────╢
║ Bold              │  *Text*  │ Type an asterisk before and after the text.       ║
╟───────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────╢
║ Strikethrough     │  ~Text~  │ Type a tilde before and after the text.           ║
╟───────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────╢
║ Monospace         │  `Text`  │ Type a backtick before and after the text.        ║
╟───────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────╢
║ Codeblock         │   ```    │ 1. Type three backticks                           ║
║                   │   Text   │ 2. Type one line break (press shift + return)     ║
║                   │   ```    │ 3. Type your text                                 ║
║                   │          │ 4. Type another line break (press shift + return) ║
║                   │          │ 5. Type three more backticks                      ║
╟───────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────╢
║ LaTeX typesetting │ \(Text\) │                                                   ║
╚═══════════════════╧══════════╧═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
````

https://www.facebook.com/help/147348452522644

[image: Facebook formatting]

Answer (score 2):

Here are the 3 known text formatting ways on Facebook.

`*This is Bold*`

`_This is italic_`

`~This is Strikethrough~`

```
`This will write Consolas font-style and disable the text formatting inside it`
```

Comment: the last one is called [monospaced style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

Comment: Yeah right @LưuVĩnhPhúc, I didn't know that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it still works but it used to be

```
*bold text here*

_underline text here_
```

I have no idea of an italic formatting option.

Comment: It doesn't work, today (August 2014).